# What is best practice for handling mixed case on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

So it is well documented that Amazon S3 only uses lowercase for bucket names and object names, so it is difficult to represent file names that may have contained uppercase letters when, for instance, backing up a file to S3.  I thought then that I would put the 'true' mixed-case filename in metadata, only to discover that the metadata also has a restriction of all lowercase(!!!).

Has anyone established a best practice or technique for representing mixed-case filenames?  I can think of methods like storing additional metadata that indicates which letters in the key or in other metadata should be uppercase, but this is a mess.

Any recommendations or common practices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean by just lowercase for objects. Yes, bucket names are lowercase but objects can have mixed case names.  Check below:

[image: MixedCase S3]

Comment: +1 and second that... there's nothing to indicate that the lowercase-only restriction applies to object keys (filenames) in S3 or metadata values. If that isn't working, that sounds like OP is using a library that may have been designed around a misinterpretation of the docs.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like you are right. Now I can't find where I read the lowercase restriction, so I must have been reading about buckets.  And indeed, the package I'm using restricts things to lowercase; I'm not sure why.  It may be because - again my reading of the docs - it appears the user metadata must be lower case.  The docs say 'Amazon S3 stores user-defined metadata in lowercase.', which frankly just boggles the mind - I can see requiring my metadata _keys_ to be lowercase, but this seems to imply that the metadata _values_ are lowercase.  Do you have experience with this?

Comment: The keys are always lowercase because they're captured/returned as custom HTTP headers. The values are not, and can be mixed case.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you so much - that makes more sense and helps a lot.

Comment: Yes. Amazon S3 stores user-defined metadata in lowercase. Each name, value pair must conform to US-ASCII when using REST and UTF-8 when using SOAP or browser-based uploads via POST. from  (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)